# How to use spring cloud sleuth to propagate token

Tags: spring-security, spring-cloud-sleuth

I need to know how the authorization is propagated using Spring sleuth and what all is need to implement for complete mechanism to propagate token received in Authorization Header.
Thanks in advance for your valuable time.

Answer (score 0):

Before asking any questions please read the documentation. If you checked it out (by searching for the word propagation or propagating) you'd see the following section https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-sleuth/2.2.1.RELEASE/reference/html/#propagating-extra-fields

If the header comes in to a Spring Cloud Sleuth based app and you want to propagate it further on, just pass it as a property `spring.sleuth.propagation-keys: Authorization` and that's it.